# Can I use a function to let all checkbox checked or unchecked(not use click trigger)?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to use a function to let all checkboxes checked or unchecked,but not use a button click to trigger.How to do it?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list" id="checkbox_<%=rs.getString("id")%>" onclick="check_marker(this)" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Now, what's the representative HTML (and what you posted appears to be a script, not HTML)?

Comment: At what time this should happen ? after page loading or any event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't clearify when do you want to that check happen, but there's function for that. It uses `for` loop for setting checkstate to all checkboxes. You can use it whenever you want in the code.

```
function checktoggle(state) { // state is true or false(true = checked, false = unchecked)
    var boxes = document.getElementsByName('list');

    for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].checked = state;
    }
}
```